# making document ID = UID firestore swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am very new to programming and wanted to know how I can make my documentID = my UID on firestore

Here is my code:

```
// create the user

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email, password: Password) { (results, Err) in

                // check for errors
                if Err != nil {
                    // there was an error creating the user

                    self.showError("Error creating user")

                }

                else {

                        // user was created succesfully store info
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()



                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["first name":Firstname, "last name":Lastname, "age":Age, "uid":results!.user.uid]) { (Error) in




                        if Error != nil {
                            // show error message
                            self.showError("error saving user data")

                        }
```

If anyone can tell me what I need to add to my code that would be amazing!!!

Also would anyone know how I would be able to access my document ID afterwards through code so I can later add/merge more information to that same document ID

Thank you very much, peace and love!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of addDocument, which uses a random ID, use build a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference) to the document you want to create, and use [setData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#setdata_:) to create it.

```
db
    .collection("users")
    .document(results!.user.uid)
    .setData(...)
```

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for more information about creating documents.

Comment: Thank you soo much doug, if I ever see you in person Im gona give you a big kiss. I have one more question for you I know you answered it im just still a little confused. If I want to merge more user info into the same document ID how would I make a reference or access that document ID?