# How to make ForEach loop for a Codable Swift Struct's Dictionary (based on Firestore map)

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, foreach, codable

I am trying to do a ForEach loop that lists all of the social medias a user might have. This would be on a scrollable list, the equivalent of music streaming apps have a list of all the songs you save in your library. The user's social medias list is in reality a **dictionary**.

My MainViewModel class implements all of the Firebase functionality. See below.

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var errorMessage = ""
@Published var user: User?

init() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.isUserCurrentlyLoggedOut = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid == nil
    }

    readCodableUserWithMap()
}

@Published var isUserCurrentlyLoggedOut = false

func handleSignOut() {
    isUserCurrentlyLoggedOut.toggle()
    try? FirebaseManager.shared.auth.signOut()
}

func readCodableUserWithMap() {
    guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
        self.errorMessage = "Could not find firebase uid"
        print("FAILED TO FIND UID")
        return
    }
    
    let userID = uid
    let docRef = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(userID)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let doc = document {
            let user = try! doc.data(as: User.self)
            if let mappedField = user.socials {
                mappedField.forEach { print($0.key, $0.value) }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**readCodableUserWithMap()** is supposed to initialize my codable struct, which represents a user. See below.

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
   @DocumentID var id: String?
   var socials: [String: String]?
   var uid, email, name, bio, profileImageUrl: String?
   var numSocials, followers, following: Int?
}
```

**QUESTION AT HAND:** In my Dashboard View, I am trying to have a list of all the social medias a user can have. I can't manage to make a ForEach loop for my user.

I do:

```
ForEach(vm.user?.socials.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
                    linkDisplay(social: key, handler: value)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)


                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
```

This gives me the following errors:

1. Value of optional type '[Dictionary<String, String>.Element]?' (aka 'Optional<Array<(key: String, value: String)>>') must be unwrapped to a value of type '[Dictionary<String, String>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: String, value: String)>')
2. Value of optional type '[String : String]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'sorted' of wrapped base type '[String : String]'

I have tried coalescing using ?? but that doesn't work, although I assume I am doing something wrong. Force-unwrapping is something I tried but it made the app crash when it was an empty dictionary.

Just in case, here is the database hierarchy: [firebase hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH6PU.png)

**TLDR:** HOW can I make a ForEach loop to list all of my user's medias?

Comment: A couple of things - optionals are optional for a reason - they could be nil. So this code `vm.user?` could crash your app if user is nil, so best to safely unwrap optionals before use - you mentioned nil coalescing operators and that's a good place to use one and/or a guard or if...let statement. Can you try just printing the vm.user.socials to console to ensure they are all read? If they are what you expect then your ForEach statement is where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both `vm.user` and `socials` as optionals.
The `ForEach` loop requires non-optionals, so
you could try the following approach to unwrap those for the `ForEach` loop.

```
    if let user = vm.user, let socials = user.socials {
        ForEach(socials.sorted(by: > ), id: \.key) { key, value in
            linkDisplay(social: key, handler: value)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }.onDelete(perform: delete)
    }
```